# Count the number of dots from the beginning of line up to the current cursor position in Emacs Lisp

Tags: emacs

Let's say I have a file with a few sentences in it and I would like to count (on every cursor position change) the number of
dots from the beginning of the line to the current cursor position, so, an example (the cursor is represented by | sign (pipe)):

```
First sentence. Second. Third. And | is the cursor. ;; 3 dots
```

or

```
First sentence. | Second. Third. ;; 1 dot
```

I hope it is clear.

I will work with this result further in code, so only the current value of dots after each change of cursor position in the buffer is important.

I will also target only specific type of files with this hook, so don't worry about performance, although I don't think it would be something too CPU intensive to calculate number of dots in a row that has cca 80 characters max, often less

Comment: Where do you want the count to "appear" ? At the end of line in a comment, in the minibuffer, stored somewhere else ... ? And is it really important to do it that frequently, or could you do it in a single pass at the end of your writing/with a function call ?

Comment: As I said, that is unimportant (message count) whatever, I just need to get the count to use it further in my code.

Comment: You can count the number of dots in the current line with `(count-matches "\\." (line-beginning-position) (line-end-position))`. To do it after each movement, you can use `post-command-hook`.

Answer (score 0):

```
 (defun count-dots-to-point ()
   (interactive)
   (let ((start (save-excursion
                  (beginning-of-line)
                  (point)))
         (end (point)))
     (message "%d" (count-matches "\\." start end))))

 (add-hook 'post-command-hook 'count-dots-to-point)
```